# YQL Data URI Error

Tags: rest, yql

I'm using the YQL Data URI table to extract Data URIs for images hosted on third party domains from within a web application.

The canonical example comes from the YQL documentation for this API:

`select * from data.uri where url="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/pps/yql32.png"`

[Here is an example of the query](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?debug=true#h=select%20%2a%20from%20data.uri%20where%20url=%22http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/pps/yql32.png%22) running in the YQL console, although I'm running it via the REST API.

If you run this example, you will see the data uri returned in the results. However, the vast majority of image url's I seem to come across do not work. Instead of a data URI, I get an error along the lines of:

`{
        "error": "128261 > 25600"
    }`

The numbers are always different, but the pattern is consistent. Here is the query that generated the above error:

`select * from data.uri where url="http://i.imgur.com/GXWwz5k.jpg"`

I've been unable to find documentation on this error. This appears to be consistent whether I'm using the console or the REST API. Does anyone have an idea of what's causing this query to fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data.uri table errors when the target file is larger than 25kb in size.

What you're seeing in the error message is "*size of target file* > size limit".